# Collision Detection between two textures in XNA

Tags: c#, windows-8, xna, windows-store-apps, monogame

I am making a game for windows store using monogame implementation of XNA where in, I am applying a flick gesture to move an object around the screen.

Here is the code I wrote in the Update method for flicking and updating the position and velocity of the object

```
            while (TouchPanel.IsGestureAvailable)
            {
                GestureSample gesture = TouchPanel.ReadGesture();
                if (gesture.GestureType == GestureType.Flick)
                    velocity += gesture.Delta;
                if (gesture.GestureType == GestureType.Hold)
                    position = gesture.Position;
            }

             if (velocity != Vector2.Zero)
             {
                float elapsedSeconds = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
                position += velocity * elapsedSeconds;
                float newMagnitude = velocity.Length() - DECELERATION * elapsedSeconds;
                velocity.Normalize();
                velocity *= Math.Max(0, newMagnitude);
            }
            UpdateSprite(gameTime, ref position, ref velocity);

        void UpdateSprite(GameTime gameTime, ref Vector2 spritePosition, ref Vector2 spriteSpeed)
        {
        // Move the sprite by speed, scaled by elapsed time.
        spritePosition += spriteSpeed * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
        int MaxX = GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width - cat.Width;
        int MinX = 0;
        int MaxY = 500 - cat.Height;
        int MinY = 0;
        // Check for bounce.
        if (spritePosition.X > MaxX - 10)
        {
            if (spritePosition.Y <= 200 || spritePosition.Y >= 300)
            {
                spriteSpeed.X *= -1;
                spritePosition.X = MaxX;
            }
            else
            {
                PositionCount = 0;
            }
        }
        else if (spritePosition.X < MinX + 10)
        {
            if (spritePosition.Y <= 200 || spritePosition.Y >= 300)
            {
                spriteSpeed.X *= -1;
                spritePosition.X = MinX;
            }
            else
            {
                PositionCount = 0;
            }
        }
        if (spritePosition.Y > MaxY)
        {
            spriteSpeed.Y *= -1;
            spritePosition.Y = MaxY;
        }
        else if (spritePosition.Y < MinY)
        {
            spriteSpeed.Y *= -1;
            spritePosition.Y = MinY;
        }
    }
```

The flicking of the object works perfect with this code. But what I am looking for is, when the user flicks the object and if the flicked object collides with any other object then the second object should also move Like how the carom coins move when the flicked striker collides with them.

I have tried putting logic for collision and movement but in vain.

Any sort of help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Depending on your desired realism, you might want to utilize a 2d physics engine, which would easily allow for multiple dynamic complex collisions. http://box2d.org is a famous physics framework that's easy to use, I utilized it myself a few times.

Comment: I am sorry but the link you provided is blank.

Comment: It should work now :)

Comment: What you are asking is more about Collision Response, than collision detection.  If all your object are circles, then yes, it isn't that complicated to do.  However, if your objects are any other shapes, and you want a sense of realism, then you are going to be programming a physics engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Farseer Physics Engine](http://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/). It's a popular C# physics engine based on Box2D and is compatible with MonoGame. It has lots of code samples and okay documentation.

Comment: yes I have stated reading for it. But is this for sure that I would need physics engine here? I mean can't I accomplish the work without using the engine? (Sorry but I am wreathed in doubts)

Comment: You don't *need* a physics engine but collision detection can be a complex topic and physics engines tend help with that. Alternately, you can start Googling for "2D collision detection" and find a tutorial. For example: http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-custom-2d-physics-engine-aabb-circle-impulse-resolution--gamedev-6331